# Value is repeated after copying it from Access and pasting it into Notepad++

Tags: ms-access, notepad++

I open a table inside the GUI of MS Access. I mark a cell which contains:

```
Myriam
```

I hit ctrl + c to copy it. I open a new document in Notepad++ and copy with strg + v. The result is:

```
"Myriam
Myriam"
```

I get two lines instead of one! There are 27 thousand entries in that column and ONLY for this one I observe this behaviour. I was able to track it down to this level, but now I'm clueless about the 'why' ... ?

Comment: In the Access GUI, select the cell in question and hit `[Shift][F2]`. See if the value is actually two copies of the name separated by a line-break.

Comment: I used [Shift][F2] and saw that there are two rows, both containing "Myriam". How does this happen? As I said, all the other 27 thousand entries are "normal".

Comment: If a user manually typed in that value they probably hit `[Ctrl][Enter]` by mistake, adding the newline and making the cell look empty. Thinking that they accidentally deleted the value, they typed it in again.

Comment: You're the hero of the day in my laboratory :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "Zoom" feature (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>) in Access revealed that the field actually did contain

```
Myriam
Myriam
```

This was probably due to a user accidentally hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> during data entry, which added the newline and made the field look empty, so they typed the name in a second time.